# Making HTTP request from backend and secure API key from outside world?

Tags: javascript, php, security, xmlhttprequest, api-key

I've a simple website which is fetching data from an API. Therefore I've to use an API key. Initially what I've done is I've called API from front end with vanilla js using `async` function and `fetch()`. But I've figure out that anyone can see my API key if I call API from front end by going to the developers tools --> network.

Therefore what I've done is I've used `fetchData.php` which makes API call and fetch data. In my `App.js` I'm making AJAX request to that `fetchData.php` file.

Q1) So Is that a good way to secure my API key? because of I'm not making my API call from front end?

Q2) Should I do something more than this to secure my API key?

Q3) Also is that the way how developer do something like this with vanilla js?

`App.js`

```
var oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();  
oXHR.open("GET", "fetchData.php", true);  
oXHR.onload = function(evt)
{
  const movies = JSON.parse(oXHR.responseText);
  movies.results.forEach(movie => {
    console.log(movie);
  })
}
oXHR.onerror = function(evt)
{
  alert("Error!");
}
oXHR.send();
```

`fetchData.php`

```
<?php 

$API_KEY = '7013---------------------';
$imgBaseURL = 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original';
$fetch_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/week?api_key=$API_KEY";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fetch_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$movies_json = curl_exec($ch);
echo $movies_json;

?>
```

Any guidance would be most helpful. Thanks!!!

Comment: [Don't post images of code and/or errors!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please also stick to one question per post or it risks getting closed for being unfocused.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can use the API key in the backend only(PHP in your case) then it will not be visible in the network tab.

There are lots of ways to secure API may be you can use JWT to authenticate the valid user and allow them to use those API.

Or you can put your backend behind the API gateway and configure the gateway as per your need.